# Regex finding reapeating group issue when comma present and 'single line' mode

Tags: regex

I could not debug this in regex101  to find why it does not work.

https://regex101.com/r/thl3ui/1

```
/^\s*@MyCustomQuery\(\s*([^\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s*\,\s*([^\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s*\,\s*([^\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s*\)/s
```

And this is the string I am trying to parse:

```
@MyCustomQuery(name = "nativeSQL", query = "SELECT emp1.emp_id, emp1.name, emp1.manager_id, "
+ "emp1.dept_id, emp1.address_id " + "FROM EMP emp1, EMP emp2 "
+ "WHERE ((emp2.EMP_ID = ?) AND (emp2.EMP_ID = emp1.MANAGER_ID))", resultClass = Professor.class)
public class SomeClass {
}
```

And the result would be:
group1 = name
group2 = "nativeSQL"
group3 = query
group4 = "SELECT emp1.emp_id, emp1.name, emp1.manager_id, "
+ "emp1.dept_id, emp1.address_id " + "FROM EMP emp1, EMP emp2 "
+ "WHERE ((emp2.EMP_ID = ?) AND (emp2.EMP_ID = emp1.MANAGER_ID))"
group5 = ... for ever until ) is found.

The regex works, but I need to have a specific number of groups, if I try to repeat it I get errors:

```
^\s*@MyCustomQuery\((\s*([^\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s*)?\,\)
```

Is it possible to repeat a capture group that contains 2 groups inside: \s*([^\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s* at every ',' and end the repetition in ')'?

Any help creating a repeating group to be able to capture the pairs of key and values in the Java class Annotation is very appreciated.

Comment: The last pattern does not match because there is no `,)` in the string. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to be able to repeat that group, so it will detect all key/value pair inside the @MyCustomQuery(name=value, name2=value2... )

Comment: You can not dynamically get capture groups that you can use like group 1, group 2 etc(Or you would have to create multiple optional groups after each other). It depends on the tool or language that may provide you with consecutive matches for that part of the string. What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I'm using Javascript to read Java files and obtain the desired annotation @'MyCustomQuery and it's contents. https://regex101.com/r/ZeuhDl/1 this is close, but I would like to have only 2 repeating groups... grabring the key value pair inside the annotation.

Comment: You might specify all the groups that you need if there can only be 2 groups `^\s*@MyCustomQuery\(\s*([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]+)", ([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*"(.*?"(?=,\s*[^\s=]+\s*=\s*[^\s=])),\s*([^\s,=]+)\s*=\s*([^\s=,]+),\s*([^\s,=]+)\s*=\s*([^\s=,]+)` https://regex101.com/r/3B6vZR/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird So I cant just have one \s*([^\s]+)\s*=\s*(.+)\s* that repeats itself indefinetily between ',' and the repetition ends in \) ?

Comment: You can repeat it, but repeating a capture group will only eventually give back the group value of the last iteration. Are you using Javascript in an environment that supports a [quantifier in a lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind)?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I did not understand this last part. But ok. Can you give an example in an answer so I can mark it as solved? I will update my question a bit to try and be more clear.

Comment: If you use javascript that allows a lookbehind, you might get the capture groups like this `(?<=^\s*@MyCustomQuery\([^]*)([^\s=,]+)\s*=\s*(?:"([^]*?)"|([^\s,=]+?))(?:,|\)$)` https://regex101.com/r/6QJEy4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird This is ALMOST perfect. Amazing. How to make it not REQUIRE the comma for the last key/value parameters? I did this: (?<=^\s*@MyCustomQuery\([^]*)([^\s=,]+)\s*=\s*(?:"([^]*?)"|([^\s,=]+?))(?:[,\)]|\)$) it seemed fine, what do you think? Can you make an answer so I can give you some credit for this. Great work.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that `How to make it not REQUIRE the comma for the last key/value parameters?` If there is not comma, how would you tell the difference? Could you give an example in the regex101 link and then save it and add it here again? https://regex101.com/r/6QJEy4/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird An improved question: How to make it require ',' comma OR ')' parenthesis for "end of group" marker?

Comment: It already does that using `(?:,|\)$)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Perfect. Please create a full answer. Thank you so much for your help and hardwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a few capture groups in the current pattern. If you want to extend a variable number of capture groups, you can not use JavaScript to repeat the capture group and then get the groups by number, like group 1, group 2 because repeating a capture group will hold the value of the last iteration.

(You can do that for example in .NET or the Python PyPi regex module to get the captures collection)

Another option is to use a long list of optional capture groups, but then you would always have to account for the maximum number.

If you use JavaScript that supports a [lookbehind assertion](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), you can get the key values pairs in group 1 and 2 by asserting the opening part from the start of the string to the left.

Note that there is a query in the example string, that also contains double quotes and comma's so this can be error prone as for the separate defined parts you have to define boundaries that you can rely on.

For the example data, you might use:

```
(?<=^\s*@MyCustomQuery\([^]*)([^\s=,()]+)\s*=\s*(?:"([^]*?)"|([^\s,=]+?))(?:,|\)$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `^\s*@MyCustomQuery\(` Match `@MyCustomQuery(` at the start of the string
  - `[^]*` Optionally repeat matching any character including newlines
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `([^\s=,()]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ occurrences of any char except the listed in the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `\s*=\s*` Match an equals sign between optional whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation, match either

  - `"([^]*?)"` Capture optional chars between double quotes in **group 2**
  - `|` Or
  - `([^\s,=]+?)` Capture 1+ times any character other than the listed in the character class, non greedy in **group 3**
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?:,|\)$)` Match either a `,` or `)` followed by the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nMql9L/1)

There are 2 different capture groups for the value. To get the group value, you can check if one of the groups is not empty.

Comment: Unfortunately I have been having some bugs... I've changed the regex a bit to fix some, If you have some time to take a look: https://regex101.com/r/zMGSnG/1 Thanks.

Comment: @BBacon The lookbehind uses `[^]*` to match any character including newlines. What you might do for example if there are characters that should not match is to exclude them like https://regex101.com/r/Wof0DV/1